# Partitioning Issues

Tags: partitioning, gparted

So I decided to include my entire HD space of 320GB in the /dev/sda3 partition where I had installed Ubuntu.

I was told that it is better to keep some HD space away from the installation partition. So I resized the partition to 50GB in order to use the rest to store data.

I created the partition /dev/sda4 and labeled it as 'Data'.

However, I am unable to copy any data into this folder. When I go to 'Data' I only see the fold 'lost+found'. But I am not able to create any other folder nor can I move my data here.

Have I done anything wrong?

Also I see that 1.75GB of space has already been taken! How can this be possible?

Here's the screenshot from the GParted Partition Editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkCQi.png

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem will likely have been created and mounted such that only `root` has write access initially; you probably want to use `sudo chown $USER /media/Data` to change its ownership, since user-mounting is not useful for partitions on internal drives.

The 1.75GB initially taken is filesystem overhead for inodes and backup superblocks.  Linux doesn't try to hide the fact that all filesystems require a certain amount of overhead.

Comment: Okay.. I don't know what happened but when I entered "sudo chown $USER /media/Data" in the terminal, it said no such file/directory exists.. I also notice that the Data partition had changed from /media/Data to /media/bc324hdsdf (some random alphanumeric).

So I copied "sudo chown $USER /media/(random alphanumeric)" into the terminal but nothing happened.
But surprisingly, now I can transfer data to the Data partition!